# Tags in opencorpora Russian corpus.

Tags: resource-request, online-resources

I am looking through xml file of [opencorpora.org](http://opencorpora.org/) and trying to understand their meaning. Here is an example:

```
<sentence id="23847">
                <source>это просто прекрасно по-моему.</source>
                <tokens>
                    <token id="434143" text="это">
                        <tfr t="это" rev_id="4440916">
                            <v>
                                <l id="386574" t="это">
                                    <g v="PRCL"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="386575" t="это">
                                    <g v="NPRO"></g>
                                    <g v="neut"></g>
                                    <g v="sing"></g>
                                    <g v="nomn"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="386575" t="это">
                                    <g v="NPRO"></g>
                                    <g v="neut"></g>
                                    <g v="sing"></g>
                                    <g v="accs"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="386581" t="этот">
                                    <g v="ADJF"></g>
                                    <g v="Subx"></g>
                                    <g v="Apro"></g>
                                    <g v="Anph"></g>
                                    <g v="neut"></g>
                                    <g v="sing"></g>
                                    <g v="nomn"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="386581" t="этот">
                                    <g v="ADJF"></g>
                                    <g v="Subx"></g>
                                    <g v="Apro"></g>
                                    <g v="Anph"></g>
                                    <g v="neut"></g>
                                    <g v="sing"></g>
                                    <g v="accs"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                        </tfr>
                    </token>
                    <token id="434144" text="просто">
                        <tfr t="просто" rev_id="1267522">
                            <v>
                                <l id="285025" t="просто">
                                    <g v="ADVB"></g>
                                    <g v="Prdx"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="285026" t="просто">
                                    <g v="PRCL"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="285050" t="прост">
                                    <g v="ADJS"></g>
                                    <g v="Qual"></g>
                                    <g v="neut"></g>
                                    <g v="sing"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                        </tfr>
                    </token>
                    <token id="434145" text="прекрасно">
                        <tfr t="прекрасно" rev_id="1267523">
                            <v>
                                <l id="267583" t="прекрасно">
                                    <g v="ADVB"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="267591" t="прекрасен">
                                    <g v="ADJS"></g>
                                    <g v="Qual"></g>
                                    <g v="neut"></g>
                                    <g v="sing"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                        </tfr>
                    </token>
                    <token id="434146" text="по-моему">
                        <tfr t="по-моему" rev_id="1267524">
                            <v>
                                <l id="241289" t="по-моему">
                                    <g v="ADVB"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                            <v>
                                <l id="241290" t="по-моему">
                                    <g v="CONJ"></g>
                                    <g v="Prnt"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                        </tfr>
                    </token>
                    <token id="434147" text=".">
                        <tfr t="." rev_id="1267525">
                            <v>
                                <l id="0" t=".">
                                    <g v="PNCT"></g>
                                </l>
                            </v>
                        </tfr>
                    </token>
                </tokens>
            </sentence>
```

Anybody knows why `это` has multiple tags? What does other tags mean such as:

```
<g v="ADJS"></g>
<g v="Qual"></g>
<g v="neut"></g>
<g v="sing"></g>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They call it *"gramemes"*. They roughly can be described tags.

The full list of these is [located here](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=gram), and the description (pretty vague) is in column #4 "Описание" ("Description").

The "gramemes" in question are (sequential numbers from table above):

- ADJS #4 "adjective/short"
- Qual #59 qualitative
- neut #27 neuter gender
- sing #30 singular

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know why `это` has two contradictory tags: `<g v="nomn"></g>` and `<g v="accs"></g>`. Also why is `этот` mentioned?

Comment: @user1700890, (1) the project is based on community input and may not be free from human mistakes; (2) the Nominative and Accusative for the `это` have the same form — see the table [here](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE#.D1.8D.D1.82.D0.BE_.28.D1.81.D1.83.D1.89.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5.29) (don't ask me why they call it a noun there)

Comment: Thank you again! I totally understand human mistakes. It would be nice if they would explain meaning of their XML. Still why `этот` is present?

Comment: @user1700890, probably because `это` is Neuter while `этот` is Masculine. If they list all distinct word forms, this make a perfect sense.

Comment: ok makes sense, then I would expect to see `эта` as feminine as well, but it is missing.

Comment: @user1700890 They're saying that there are five possible parses: `это` could be the particle `это`, or two different forms of the pronoun `это`, or two different forms of the adjective `этот`. The convention is to list the masculine singular nominative as the "default" form of an adjective.